# node modules continuous build

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, build

How to build dependent modules in right order? For example we have setup jenkins for npm build today. For eg we have 3 modules a ,b ,c .A has dependency on b and c.
When a developer checks in code for a and c, I must ensure c is build ahead of A.How can I achieve this with jenkins /jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to Manage Inter-Project Dependencies using Jenkins](http://www.vedantatree.com/2012/06/how-to-manage-inter-project.html) you may setup **Job** and **Post Build** to achieve.

Comment: this may not solve my purpose. The problem I am facing is other way around.Developers(more than one) can checkin to the repositories in respective module any time. If they make changes to  B and A and check in the code at the same time.The web hook will trigger build for both, but I would like it to wait until the dependant module for A (ie B's) build is completed.Said this is there way to submit build in order? rather than configuring hooks on each module?

Comment: No matter the sequence of code commit, Jenkins should build everything again. First, following the article you should conf your dependencies well. Second, your dev should have the same set of source code as Jenkin, so if he success to build the project, it means that jenkin should successfully build too because both environment should have same build script.